# Print linked to the logical value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Good morning I wanted help for a code that can use a logical value example:
`` `

```
function provaIf2(){
var A2=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2').getValue();
var C4=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C4').getValue();
if(A2=="") SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B2').activate();
else if(A2<C4) Print the sheet
else if(A2==C4) Print the sheet
else SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3').activate();
}
```

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: I put an example

Comment: @SourabhSomani ok

Comment: @FrancescoSantoro, what exactly are you trying to do? And more precisely, what is your question? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 I would like that when A2 is less than or equal to C4 it automatically prints the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **print** a document using Apps Script, you will have to use **Google Cloud Print**.

As explained in this article [here](https://www.labnol.org/code/20061-google-cloud-print-with-apps-script), you will have to create an Apps Script project in which you include the OAuth2 library. Then you need to **get** the Google Cloud Print service, send the request and last but not least, print the document.

The below code snippet is used to print the document with the desired options:

```js
function printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName) {

  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR",
        vendor_id: "Color"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      }
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid" : printerID,
    "title"     : docName,
    "content"   : DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getBlob(),
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "ticket"    : JSON.stringify(ticket)
  };
```

- **Reference:** [Automatically Print Files Placed in Drive with Google Cloud Print and Apps Script](https://www.labnol.org/code/20061-google-cloud-print-with-apps-script).

Comment: So let me explain better I would like to use a system like the mail merge between Excel and Publisher but I would like to do it with the Google sheet database and contract sheet linked to the database